# Create a method that deserializes a serialized object.

Tags: c#, winforms, class, xmlserializer, bindinglist

I would like to create a method that Deserializes a serialized class.

Codes:

```
Settings newSettings = new Settings(); //Settings is a class.
Settings lastSettings = new Settings();
private void LoadXML(Type type,string filepath)
{
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open);
Settings newset = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(fs); //Deserializes a serializable class file.
newSettings = newset; //Sets these settings as NewSettings
lastSettings = newSettingsXML; //Before form opening, sets information into form.
fs.Close();
}
```

Now i want to do these with a method. I created also different method for "Person" Class. This method reads person from xml file and sets these person into the form.

```
private void PersonFromXML(string filepath)
{
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Person>));
FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open);
BindingList<Person> XML_Person = (BindingList<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
NEW_XML_Person = XML_Person; // These are BindingList<Person>.
fs.Close();
Grid_Person.DataSource = XML_Person;
}
```

I want to do these Deserializing methods as one different Method. I want to write this method into a dll file.
I tried to do these:

```
private BindingList<Type> FromXML(BindingList<Type> type,string filepath)
{
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(type));
FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open);
BindingList<Type> BL = (type)ser.Deserialize(fs);
fs.Close();
return BL;
}
```

But it did NOT work. Because i could not set BindingList type as Person.. What should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: Please pick a more specific title for your question. Almost all C#-related questions in here are essentially about how to "create a method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to set your generic type parameter on your method declaration.

Try this:

```
public static class MySerializationHelper
{
   public static class From
   {
      public TReturn XMLFile<TReturn>(string contents)
      {
         var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TReturn));
         var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
         var result = (TReturn)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
         fs.Close();
         return result;
      }
   }

   public static class To
   {
      public void XMLFile<TType>(TType object, string filePath)
      {
         // Serialize it here...
      }
   }
}
```

Than, you may simply use it, like:

```
var bindingList = MySerializationHelper.From.XmlFile<IBindingList<Person>>("Persons.xml");
var person = MySerializationHelper.From.XmlFile<Person>("Person_1.xml");

MySerializationHelper.To.XmlFile<IBindingList<Person>>(bindingList, "Persons_copy.xml");
MySerializationHelper.To.XmlFile<Person>(person, "Person_1_Copy.xml");
```

Comment: Just so you know: you *don't* have to use that inner-class structure. That's my personal style because on this type of helpers I'd place all serialization/deserialization, including XML, TXT, DBF, etc (and using internal classes make it cleaner and easier to find something). Should be quite fine to just remove that inner classes, if you want to.